# Protocol for RS485 network?

Tags: rs485, bus, protocol

I have to build a sensor network which communicates over a single RS485 bus. The network could have tens of nodes. The problem is that I have to control access to the shared bus and find a way to address each node, similar to TCP/IP. Each sensor (when it is triggered) can send data asynchronously to the server.

**Is there a protocol available for a RS485 network? If so, is it free?**
The protocol would be implemented in a microcontroller.

**Can I use a controller with TCP/IP stack?**

**Has anybody designed such a network?** I am curious if my approach is correct in order to know if it's OK to continue on this path or if I have to switch to a different techology.

Comment: There are lots of protocols in use - grab a manual for something that speaks RS845 in a shared setting.  Typically a master sends out the address of who it wants to talk to, and only that node may reply only then.  But a more peer to peer scheme with collision detection and random backoff could be possible.

Comment: TCP/IP does not control shared bus access; this is done by a lower protocol.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I my case the sensors communicate with a server and each sensor (when it is triggered) can send data asynchronously to the server.

Comment: Go for modbus. 1234567890

Comment: Collision detection can be difficult (not impossible) with RS485 as neither high nor low are dominant and a device monitoring the bus while transmitting may only see it's own transmission despite a collision with a device down the line. There was an answer here a year or few ago that showed a modification for collision detection. I'll pass on a link if I find it. I've used modbus and added polling based on address dependant timeslots to avoid collisions while determining what slaves were connected.

Comment: This answer by Dave Tweed may be what I was remembering: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/62380/25328 (I haven't tried this)

Comment: You might consider CAN as an alternative to RS485: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/304546/25328

Comment: Many free-to-use protocols are listed at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Systems/Common_Protocols ; most of them would work on RS485 physical link hardware.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a demo about transfer TCP/IP through RS485:
https://github.com/dukelec/cdbus_doc

The protocol on RS485 is CDBUS, which could use a standalone controller to solve the collision problem, you can also implement CDBUS protocol by software, or simply don't take care about collision, re-sent packet when data lost was detected.
The CDBUS protocol: https://github.com/dukelec/cdbus_ip

The upon protocol is CDNET, is similar to UDP protocol, you can send UDP packet from MCU by only few line of codes and without any library, but need a gateway to translate CDNET to real TCP/IP protocol.
Or you can define your own protocol, and translate them on the gateway.